# Not getting location updates using Google play services API with mobile data in android

Tags: android, service, location, google-play-services

I am making an android application to get current location via service and upload to database using Google play services fused API but the problem I am facing is that whenever I am trying to get location via my home wifi its working fine and i am getting regular location updates but when i switch to mobile data I am not getting correct updates, regular updates are there but its showing the same values of coordinates i.e. latitude and longitude again and again no matter hwere i am moving. Please helpme solving this issue as I am new to android development.

This is my Myservices.java where i have all the necessary code:

```
package com.maps.saury.location;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class Myservice extends Service implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    BGTask bgtask = new BGTask(this);

    public static String data;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static Location mLastLocation;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private  LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 100; 
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 100; 
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 0; 

    final class Mythreadclass implements Runnable {



        @Override
        public void run() {

            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Mythreadclass());
        thread.start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"destroyed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    private void displayLocation() {


       // mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
         //       .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            data=Double.toString(latitude)+"\n"+Double.toString(longitude);
            Toast.makeText(this,data,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            BGTask bgtask = new BGTask(this);
            bgtask.execute(Double.toString(latitude), Double.toString(longitude));

        } else {


                    Toast.makeText(this,"Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     * */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }


    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
       mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }


    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        Toast.makeText(this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Locatn changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is my AndroidMainfest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.maps.saury.location">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".Myservice"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that location updates are getting in when you are running it in debug mode at home/office and if you build the release version of the app and go outside, then the location updates are not getting in. If that is the case, then make sure that you are defined correct Google Maps API key for "release" build variant.

Comment: and how to do so? And BTW i have no maps integrated in the app so why to use api key for maps? Can you please explain

Comment: In my app, I subscribe to location updates in `onResume` method:


`Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

String bestLocationProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestLocationProvider, 1000L /* once in 1 second */, 0.0f /* distance is unknown */, this);`

and my activity implements `LocationListener` interface.